# How Can I Run A Code Snippet In Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I purchased a product importer plugin and it has this code snipped.

https://www.webtoffee.com/how-to-import-csvs-from-multiple-urls/

```
function wt_multi_csv_url_import_array(){

    return array(
        'http://example.com/pro/url_test/Sample%20Products.csv',
        'http://example.com/pro/url_test/Product_WooCommerce_Sample_CSV.csv'
       );
}

add_filter('hf_multi_csv_url_import_array','wt_multi_csv_url_import_array');
```

It allows to import csv files from different url-s instead of one by one.
I added this code and changed the urls to mine but it didnt do anything.

I dont know if i just have to save this code or somehow run it on the site.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

You will have to place this in the functions.php of your (child) theme or use a plugin like [Code Snippets](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/).

Comment: i did and nothing happened.

Comment: Please clarify what you did exactly. Did you add it to the functions.php file or did you use the Code Snippets plugin? You could ad `die('Filter was called');` at the top of your function to see if the filter gets called (which would stop all code after it from being executed and print "Filter was called"). If this is the case then you know the filter is being called but there is something wrong with your function code. I would check for errors in the error log (WooCommerce > Status > Logs) or contact plugin support for the import plugin to see if they can help you along.